# wrong php date()?

Tags: php, date-time, functions

hey guys,
it's weird and I've never experienced that before. I've created a new blog and a custom theme. I'm using `<?php echo date("H:i"); ?>`in my theme.

The time that's put is 2h earlier. e.g. if it's actually 16:00 o'clock the date generated with date() is 14:00.

I don't know why that happens? I'm using the german wordpress version with the german language pack.

Also doesn't make a difference when putting

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE');
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
```

into wp-config.php.

any idea how I could solve that? the time set in my wordpress settings is UTC+2 which is the correct time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could probably make exquisite debugging session, but taking in account it's Friday evening - just use [`date_i18n()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/date_i18n) instead and let WordPress deal with a huge mess that time/date issues usually are.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't the PHP `date()` function merely return a value based on the *server* timestamp? So, what is the current time for your server, compared to your local time? Does that account for the two-hour difference?

Comment: Yes, but it's influenced by `date_default_timezone_set()` which is set to UTC in wp-settings.php, so you'll always get UTC timecode unless you add in the GMT offset.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
echo date('H:i', current_time('timestamp'));
```

and enjoy!

Comment: I'm not sure that date_i18n() will solve the offset issue. wp-settings.php sets `date_default_timezone_set('UTC')` and all subsequent calls to date() will be based on that offset unless you switch it. date_i18n() doesn't do anything about this, just looks at the locale for formatting information. The WordPress function `current_time()` on the other hand, will take the current `time()` and then adds the GMT offset as defined in your Settings > General pane, which gives you your effective local time, provided you've set it correctly in your Settings. +1

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that the server date is different between your.
Your server has a different `date` between your probably because it's placed in another state.